# CSV file for user download, but stuck at file size around 500 KB

Tags: php, csv, download, export-to-csv, fwrite

**UPDATE:** Look like it's my misunderstanding. The cause is on the library file that have problem with **memory leak issue** with PHP 5. So every time with heavy load like these is pass to the function, their document said **I must clear the memory each time I created a new object.

Apologize to my bad code investigation.

---

- Engine: PHP 5.6 without framework
- Browser: Chrome 68.0.3440.106
- Server: XAMPP 3.2.2 bundle

What do I do for the code below is collect the data as assoc array, then sent to this function, and function will manage to write the file over network.

This function I find solution from **stackoverflow** and it worked for a small size of data.

Problem has occur with the data with very large size, I don't know how much of it. But it contains with over 50 rows and over 300 columns. Each cell contain with **blank string** or **numeric**, or **text of Japanese words**.

Code is work fine until the download process, I monitor with Chrome and when view with **all download** page (`Ctrl+J`), it always stuck at 492 KB and infinite loop of loading progress bar, until it reach the `max_execution_time` that I set to **30 minutes**.

I have download part written like this:

```
function downloadArrayAsCsv($rows, $fileName) {

    // BOM (Byte Order Mark)!!!
    echo "\xEF\xBB\xBF";

    header_remove();
    header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=Shift-JIS');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $fileName . '"');

    $fp = fopen('php://output', 'w');

    $_row = '';
    foreach ($rows as $row) {
        foreach($row as $k => $r) {

            if(is_string($r) && (intval($r)==0 || preg_match('/[A-Za-z\p{Hiragana}\p{Katakana}\p{Han}]+/', $r)) && !empty($r))
                $_row .= '"'.trim(preg_replace('/[\"]+/', '""', $r)).'"';
            else
                $_row .= $r;

            $_row .= ',';
        }
        $_row = substr($_row, 0, -1);
        $_row .= "\r\n";

        fwrite($fp, $_row);
        $_row = '';
    }

    fclose($fp);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to edit your php.ini file:

```
memory_limit = 640M
max_input_time = 1000
post_max_size = 2000M
file_uploads = On
upload_max_filesize = 200M
max_file_uploads = 200
allow_url_fopen = On
```

Comment: Can you explain which of these settings are really needed? For example, `post_max_size` looks unnecessary to me, as there is no `POST` involved